# Specific routing for subdomains and wildcard domain on HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

How could I achieve the correcting routing for specific subdomains and then route any domains that doesnt match any of the previous ACLSs?

```
frontend web_dashs
    mode http
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/domain/
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto  https
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    acl domain_a hdr_sub(host) -i a.domain.com
    acl domain_b hdr_sub(host) -i b.domain.com
    acl wilds hdr(host) -i 
    # Default Route to normal backends 
    use_backend backend_a if domain_a 
    use_backend backend_b if domain_b
    use_backend backend_c if wilds
```

Basically, what i'm trying to do is basically:

a. ----> backend A
b. ----> backend B
*.-----> backend C

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ACL is not needed for matching the rest, just use default_backend:

```
frontend web_dashs
mode http
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/domain/
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto  https
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
acl domain_a hdr_sub(host) -i a.domain.com
acl domain_b hdr_sub(host) -i b.domain.com

use_backend backend_a if domain_a 
use_backend backend_b if domain_b

default_backend backend_c
```